# I can not get Datastax DevCenter to connect to a remote database

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax

When I try to set up a connection, I get the error

> Unable to connect to 'Test Cluster': All host(s) tried for query failed
>   Unexpected error during transport initialization ... (host ip adresses) Channel has been closed

The remote database is on port 9161, which I added on the "Native port protocol" line.

Additionally is has a username or password, which I also added in the set up. This is all on a 64bit Windows machine.

Comment: Never mind. I put the port to 9042 and it worked.

Comment: This is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575640/datastax-devcenter-fails-to-connect-to-the-remote-cassandra-database/20598599#20598599 (in this case it's the port)

Answer (score 0):

i did have same your error!!
you have to open cmd firt
type "cd "
type "cassandra" to run cassandra server 
then, you try again in DevCenter with localhost and port: 9042
*i hope it may help you! ^^*

Answer (score 0):

There is another common scenario where this might happen in case someone stumbles upon this thread in the future.

This type of thing typically happens when the host crashes expectantly resulting in the corruption of the sstables or commitlog files.

This is why it is really important to use replication since when you get into this situation you can run nodetool repair to repair the corrupted tables and data from other nodes.

If you are not fortunate enough to have replication configured, then you are in for some data loss. Clear the suspect file from \data\commitlogs, cry a little and restart the node.