# DataStax Devcenter fails to connect to the remote cassandra db

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I've installed DataStax cassandra and it is up and running on my remote machine. Now I am trying to connecto via DataStax Devcenter but it fails.

Before posting this question I've read identical here: [DataStax Devcenter fails to connect to the remote cassandra database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575640/datastax-devcenter-fails-to-connect-to-the-remote-cassandra-database)

I went to `cassandra.yaml` conf file but `start_native_transport: true` option is not in my file. Where should I look for it? 
Also I've changed rpc_address to: 0.0.0.0.

UPDATE:

If I add `start_native_transport: true` into my `cassandra.yaml` it just crashes on Cassandra restart. Please refer a log below:

```
ERROR 17:48:32,626 Fatal configuration error error
Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=start_native_transport for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@ef28a30; Unable to find property 'start_native_transport' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
 in "<reader>", line 10, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
    ^

        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:372)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructObject(BaseConstructor.java:177)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.constructDocument(BaseConstructor.java:136)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:122)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Loader.load(Loader.java:52)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:166)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadYaml(DatabaseDescriptor.java:141)
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:116)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.setup(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:124)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.AbstractCassandraDaemon.activate(AbstractCassandraDaemon.java:389)
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:107)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Cannot create property=start_native_transport for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@ef28a30; Unable to find property 'start_native_transport' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:305)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.construct(Constructor.java:184)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructYamlObject.construct(Constructor.java:370)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.error.YAMLException: Unable to find property 'start_native_transport' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.getProperty(Constructor.java:342)
        at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor$ConstructMapping.constructJavaBean2ndStep(Constructor.java:240)
        ... 12 more
null; Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=start_native_transport for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@ef28a30; Unable to find property 'start_native_transport' on class: org.apache.cassandra.config.Config
Invalid yaml; unable to start server.  See log for stacktrace.
```

Thanks for any Help!

Comment: Double check the changes that you have made to your `cassandra.yaml`.  This error usually happens when you forget to close a quote or something else that alters the ability of Cassandra to parse the yaml file.

Comment: Whats your cassandra version?

Answer (score 1):

`start_native_transport: true`

should be there in cassandra.yaml if its not there then you should add it into cassandra.yaml and try after restarting the Cassandra server

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried what you said but unfortunately I am getting such error! Please refer an update!

Comment: which version of Cassandra you are using ?

Comment: Following to @kkmishra question, I believe that `start_native_transport` setting appeared in Cassandra 1.2, so if you are using an older version that could explain the startup error.

Answer (score 1):

1. What version of Cassandra are you using? DevCenter supports Cassandra versions >= 1.2
2. If you still see errors with the change in cassandra.yaml you can post a link to a Gist. But the YAML format is pretty simple so I think you'll figure it out.
3. If you read my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20598599/485496) you'll notice that it required the `rpc_address` to be set to a **different** value than `0.0.0.0`. Anyways the latest version of DevCenter (1.1.1) will work even all the nodes in your cluster have the `rpc_address` set to `0.0.0.0` (as a side note I don't think that's generally a good setting).

Answer (score 1):

DevCenter.ini does not have java VM information.
Adding below line of VM info helped resolve connection issue.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\JDK64\1.8.0.74\jre\bin\java.exe
```

NOTE: above line represents appropriate java.exe from JRE version